# Jquery on mouse out, menu hide not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am working on a code in which hidden menu will show when user mouse over on title (Menu) and after a certain time  title (Menu) will hide if user is not visiting on Hidden- menu(Which is now showing) means not working with Hidden- menu (Which is now showing)..

http://jsbin.com/icobin/12

```
   $(document).ready(function(){

        $(function(){
            jQuery.fn.delay = function(millis,callBack){
                var object = $(this);
                $.extend(object,{callBack:callBack});
                return window.setTimeout(function() {
                    object.callBack();
                    return object;
                }, millis);
            };
        });

        var navFadeOutDelay = 500; // Set delay for drop down to slide down (in ms)

        // Navigation:
        var nav = {count:0};

        $(function(){
            $("#navigtion_wrap #navigation_top").hide(); //hide navigation on page load. 

            $('#nav_menu_text').bind('hover',function(){ 
                // On mouseenter, hide title and show navigation
 $("#navigtion_wrap #nav_menu_text").hide();
 $("#navigtion_wrap #navigation_top").fadeIn();

              nav.count += 1;
            }).bind('hoverend',function(){ // On mouseleave, fade out navigation and show title
                var tmp = nav.count;
                $("#navigtion_wrap #navigation_top").delay(navFadeOutDelay, function(){ 
                    // Delay: wait X ms before navigation FadeOut                

                    if (tmp == nav.count) { 
                        // prevent delay from firing if user hovers navigation before the end of delay
                        $(this).fadeOut('slow', function(){ //Callback                  
                            $("#navigtion_wrap #nav_menu_text").show(); 
                        }); 
                    }               
                });   
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: since element ids should be unique, your selectors are redundant and you can shorten `$('#navigtion_wrap #nav_menu_text')` to `$('#nav_menu_text')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $('#navigtion_wrap #nav_menu_text').mouseover(function(){
    // on mouse over
    $(this).hide();
    $("#navigtion_wrap #navigation_top").fadeIn();
});

$('#navigtion_wrap #navigation_top').mouseleave(function(){
    // on mouse leave
    $(this).fadeOut();
    $("#navigtion_wrap #nav_menu_text").show();
});
```

Comment: @ D.clixer : hi, i also tried with your but result i is this http://jsbin.com/icobin/8